# Customizating the related list so that user can sort the specific column

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement where the user should be able to sort(ascending and descending) on clicking the specific columns.

[image]

As you can see in the above snapshot.In the contact related list when user clicks on any of its columns the values should be sorted.I am newbie so please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: consider https://github.com/Up2Go/visualforce-table-grid

Comment: Hi crop1645, 
Thanks for the reply...do i need to create visualforce page for this scenario?

Comment: yes, VF is required